# how to stop UnboundLocalError referenced before assignment

Tags: python

the following code should generate random value until I pressed `N` but just a few continuous run, it will then stop and produce `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tenpercent_mean' referenced before assignment`

```
import random
from tabulate import tabulate
from statistics import mean
import colorama
colorama.init() #colorama

FORCE_MAX   = 355
FORCE_MIN   = 250
SAMPLE_WEIGHT_MIN   = 2680
SAMPLE_WEIGHT_MAX   = 2830
SAMPLE_WEIGHT_STEP  = 5 #end with 0 or 5
POF_MIN             = 7.5 #percentage of fines
POF_MAX             = 12.5#percentage of fines
TENPERCENT_LIMIT    = 150 #kN
############ TARGET ###############
MEAN_TEN_PERCENT_FINES_VALUE   = range(240,330)
############ TARGET ###############

def main():
    while True:
        ten_percent_value()
        i = input('Continue (Y/N): ')
        if i == 'N' or i == 'n':
            break

def ten_percent_value():
    while True:
        s1 = random.randrange(SAMPLE_WEIGHT_MIN,SAMPLE_WEIGHT_MAX,SAMPLE_WEIGHT_STEP)
        s2 = random.randrange(SAMPLE_WEIGHT_MIN,SAMPLE_WEIGHT_MAX,SAMPLE_WEIGHT_STEP)

        while s1 != s2:
            pof = random.uniform(POF_MIN,POF_MAX) #get random percentage of passing
            s1_passing_sieve = rounding((pof/100)*s1) #recalculate the percentage of passing based on the new weight
            s2_passing_sieve = rounding((pof/100)*s2)

            s1_force = rounding(random.randrange(FORCE_MIN,FORCE_MAX)) #get random maximum penetration in 10minutes, end with 0 or 5
            s2_force = rounding(random.randrange(FORCE_MIN,FORCE_MAX))

            s1_tenpercent = tenpercent(s1_force,s1_passing_sieve/s1*100) #calculate the tenpercent fines value
            s2_tenpercent = tenpercent(s2_force,s2_passing_sieve/s2*100)

            tenpercent_mean = round(mean([s1_tenpercent,s2_tenpercent])) #calculate the mean of the tenpercent fines value to be compared with the limit
            break
        if tenpercent_mean > TENPERCENT_LIMIT:
            break

    print(colorama.Back.GREEN+'****** 10% Fines Values ******')
    print(colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)
    print(tabulate([['Sample Weight, g',s1,s2],['Force of Penetration, kN',s1_force,s2_force],['Weight passing 2.36, g',s1_passing_sieve,s2_passing_sieve]],headers=['','Sample (1)','Sample (2)'],tablefmt='grid'))
    print('Ten Percent Fines Value: ',tenpercent_mean)
    print('\n')

#rounding number to nearest 0 or 5            
def rounding(x, base=5):
    return base * round(x/base)

#ten percent fine FORMULA
def tenpercent(force,percent):
    return (14*force)/(percent+4)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I am using Python 3.8.2 if that has anything to with it

Comment: you have to define a default value for tenpercent_mean before get into the while loop. if the condition of the loop is false then tenpercent_mean will be undefined.

Comment: hi, where do I add the value? I add the `tenpercent_mean =0` before `def main()` but after few `Y`, it still produce `UnboundLocalError`

Comment: also your while s1 != s2: with that break at the end is the same as an if statement. and your code will never stop when you press N. because you have an infinite loop inside another infinite loop

Comment: regarding `while s1 != s2`, if i dont add the break, it will continuously run without any value

Comment: you have to define it in ten_percent_value(), or you can define in main() but you will need to pass it toten_percent_value() as parameter

Comment: if it is *not* the case that `s1 != s2` then you'll never enter the `while` block, and `tenpercent_mean` will never get assigned... your while-loop doesnt really make any sense to begin with, because you *always* `break`

Comment: then you can change that `while s1 != s2` to an if... and no need to brake

Answer (score 2):

1)
About an error :
It seems to be that you have got that time two similar numbers `s1` and `s2`. 
That's why inner `while` loop didn't run, and `tenpercent_mean` wasn't assigned.

2)
Well, your break instruction will stop only inner `while` loop(with condition `s1! =s2`), then you're going to stuck forever in outer `while` loop, cause you haven't managed to break it. That's why you're getting two similar numbers sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to you all, now after reading all your comment, it is really silly to add the `while` in another `while`, I change to `if`. Following @efirvida suggestion, I have manage to run the code without the `unboundLocalError` even after a lot of `Y`

the updated code:

```
import random
from tabulate import tabulate
from statistics import mean
import colorama
colorama.init() #colorama

FORCE_MAX   = 355
FORCE_MIN   = 250
SAMPLE_WEIGHT_MIN   = 2680
SAMPLE_WEIGHT_MAX   = 2830
SAMPLE_WEIGHT_STEP  = 5 #end with 0 or 5
POF_MIN             = 7.5 #percentage of fines
POF_MAX             = 12.5#percentage of fines
TENPERCENT_LIMIT    = 150 #kN
############ TARGET ###############
MEAN_TEN_PERCENT_FINES_VALUE   = range(240,330)
############ TARGET ###############

def main():
    while True:
        ten_percent_value()
        i = input('Continue (Y/N): ')
        if i == 'N' or i == 'n':
            break

def ten_percent_value():
    tenpercent_mean = 0 #default value to avoid UnboundLocalError
    while True:
        s1 = random.randrange(SAMPLE_WEIGHT_MIN,SAMPLE_WEIGHT_MAX,SAMPLE_WEIGHT_STEP)
        s2 = random.randrange(SAMPLE_WEIGHT_MIN,SAMPLE_WEIGHT_MAX,SAMPLE_WEIGHT_STEP)

        if s1 != s2:
            pof = random.uniform(POF_MIN,POF_MAX) #get random percentage of passing
            s1_passing_sieve = rounding((pof/100)*s1) #recalculate the percentage of passing based on the new weight
            s2_passing_sieve = rounding((pof/100)*s2)

            s1_force = rounding(random.randrange(FORCE_MIN,FORCE_MAX)) #get random maximum penetration in 10minutes, end with 0 or 5
            s2_force = rounding(random.randrange(FORCE_MIN,FORCE_MAX))

            s1_tenpercent = tenpercent(s1_force,s1_passing_sieve/s1*100) #calculate the tenpercent fines value
            s2_tenpercent = tenpercent(s2_force,s2_passing_sieve/s2*100)

            tenpercent_mean = round(mean([s1_tenpercent,s2_tenpercent])) #calculate the mean of the tenpercent fines value to be compared with the limit

        if tenpercent_mean > TENPERCENT_LIMIT:
            break

    print(colorama.Back.GREEN+'****** 10% Fines Values ******')
    print(colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)
    print(tabulate([['Sample Weight, g',s1,s2],['Force of Penetration, kN',s1_force,s2_force],['Weight passing 2.36, g',s1_passing_sieve,s2_passing_sieve]],headers=['','Sample (1)','Sample (2)'],tablefmt='grid'))
    print('Ten Percent Fines Value: ',tenpercent_mean)
    print('\n')

#rounding number to nearest 0 or 5            
def rounding(x, base=5):
    return base * round(x/base)

#ten percent fine FORMULA
def tenpercent(force,percent):
    return (14*force)/(percent+4)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: now you can change you `while true:` for `while  tenpercent_mean > TENPERCENT_LIMIT` and remove the if and the other break. using break and continue is a bad programing practice. so try to avoid it  in the future.

Comment: thanks! i am using `while tenpercent_mean < TENPERCENT_LIMIT:` because my initial `tenpercent_mean` is 0. I have no idea using `break` and `continue`  is considered bad practice but from this experience, it really is good to avoid the `if...break` code